Searching for a term for the stationnary point of $f:\mathbb{R}^2\mapsto x^3-y^3$
I am writing some notes and need clarification regarding stationary points for different types of functions.

The equation $ z = f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2 $ represents a paraboloid of revolution. There is only one stationary point at $ (0, 0) $. At this point, we have $ \Delta > 0 $ and $ f_{xx} > 0 $. Therefore, the function has a local minimum at $ (0, 0) $, where it takes the value $ 0 $.

The equation $ z = f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2 $ represents a hyperbolic paraboloid. There is only one stationary point at $ (0, 0) $. At this point, we have $ \Delta < 0 $. The function has a saddle point at $ (0, 0) $, where it takes the value $ 0 $.

The equation $ z = f(x, y) = x^3 - y^3 $ represents a cubic surface. There is only one stationary point at $ (0, 0) $. At this point, we have $ \Delta = 0 $. The second derivative test is inconclusive since $ \Delta = 0 $. The sign of $ D_{(0,0)}f = f(h,k) - f(0,0) = h^3 - k^3 = (h - k)(h^2 + hk + k^2) $ is not constant.


I am trying to determine what to call the stationary point at $ (0, 0) $ in this case. It appears to behave like an inflection point for the function $ f:\mathbb{R} \to x^3 $.

What is the appropriate term for such a stationary point that is neither a maximum nor a minimum?

Can one still refer to this point as a saddle point?


Thank you very much for your time and help!
